# New issue in server Php Laravel Sanctum Unauthenticated 401 after login live server

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, unauthorized

Local server is ok but Laravel  Sanctum Unauthenticated 401 after login live server

.env file app url check.

Database check generate token.

Server optimize clear run in server

My project is subdomain.

Local server work fine check.

Other server check is work but my new subdomain not work